# Defining operation $*$ as $x*y=\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$, what is the value of $1*(2*(3*(4*5)))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> We are defining the operation $*$ in rational numbers set as
> $$x*y=\frac{x+y}{1+xy}$$ What is the value of $1*(2*(3*(4*5)))$ ?
>
> $1)1\qquad\qquad2)15\qquad\qquad3)\frac32\qquad\qquad4)\frac45\qquad\qquad5)4$

To solve this problem I just evaluated the expression,

$$4*5=\frac37\qquad\qquad3*(4*5)=\frac32\qquad\qquad2*(3*(4*5))=\frac78$$
And finally $$1*(2*(3*(4*5)))=1$$

Although it is very easy to do these calculations I think there is some elegant method to obtain $1$. Can you please solve it with other approaches?

Comment: Check what happens when x or y equals 1.

Comment: @FatsoBoo Very nice! I got the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have gone the long way.

Note that  if $y\neq -1$,  $$1*y = \frac {1+y}{1+y} =1 $$

Thus $$ 1*(2*(3*(4*5))) =1$$

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more general remark on this problem.

For a number $x$, we let $s(x)$ denote the number $\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}$. It is easy to see that $s(s(x)) = x$.

We then have $s(x * y) = s(x)s(y)$.

This shows that the operation $*$ is commutative and associative. Furthermore, for any numbers $a_1, \dots, a_n$, the value of $a_1 * a_2 * \dots * a_n$ can be calculated as $$s\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n s(a_i)\right).$$ Since $s(1) = 0$, we obtain in particular that $1*(\textrm{anything}) = s(0) = 1$.

<sub>Special attention should be paid to the definition of $s(-1)$. This can be interpreted in projective coordinates, which I omit the details here.</sub>